# Assigning a variable in react native styleSheet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on a react native component. I want to assign the height of an image to a specific value that is calulated dynamically with the screen width. I am storing the value in a variable `aspectHeight`. I want to assign that value to the height in the stylesheet that I am currently calling. It is giving me the issue that the variable can not be found and I do not know how to solve this issue. I checked and I couldnt find any type of solution for this issue.

Here is my component;

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'

export default function PropertyTile() {

  let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 16
  var aspectHeight = (deviceWidth / 1.78) + 1

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.mainImage} source={require('../../assets/luxury-home-1.jpeg')}/>
      </View>
      <View className='content-container'>
        <Text>asdfas Tile</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    padding: 8
  },
  imageContainer: {
    height: aspectHeight,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  },
  mainImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
})
```

Comment: Your stylesheet is outside the scope of the function. Move it inside if you want to access the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with this;

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

export default function PropertyTile() {

  let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 16
  var aspectHeight = (deviceWidth / 1.78) + 1

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={[styles.imageContainer,{height: aspectHeight}]}>
        <Image style={styles.mainImage} source={require('../../assets/luxury-home-1.jpeg')}/>
      </View>
      <View className='content-container'>
        <Text>asdfas Tile</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    padding: 8
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  },
  mainImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
})
```

Nice day, good sir